# Turn an array of strings to csv format

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, replace

I have an array of strings:

```
let transactions = [
    "   Date     ||  Credit   ||  Debit   ||  Balance  ",
    "20/01/2019  ||          ||  9.00  ||  162.00",
    "20/01/2019  ||  90.00  ||          ||  171.00",
    "20/01/2019  ||          ||  9.00  ||  81.00",
    "20/01/2019  ||  90.00  ||          ||  90.00"
];
```

I turned it to this using `transactions.replace(/\s/g, '')`

```
"Date||Credit||Debit||Balance20/01/2019||||9.00||162.0020/01/2019||90.00||||171.0020/01/2019||||9.00||81.0020/01/2019||90.00||||90.00"
```

and I am trying to remove all the `|` from it and replace them with commas.

This is actually not working `transactions.replace(/|{2,}/g,",")`:

> error Invalid regular expression: /|{2}/: Nothing to repeat

And `transactions.replace(/|{+}/g,",")` returns:

```
",D,a,t,e,|,|,C,r,e,d,i,t,|,|,D,e,b,i,t,|,|,B,a,l,a,n,c,e,2,0,/,0,1,/,2,0,1,9,|,|,|,|,9,.,0,0,|,|,1,6,2,.,0,0,2,0,/,0,1,/,2,0,1,9,|,|,9,0,.,0,0,|,|,|,|,1,7,1,.,0,0,2,0,/,0,1,/,2,0,1,9,|,|,|,|,9,.,0,0,|,|,8,1,.,0,0,2,0,/,0,1,/,2,0,1,9,|,|,9,0,.,0,0,|,|,|,|,9,0,.,0,0,"
```

All I want is a csv format:

```
"Date,Credit,Debit,Balance,20/01/2019,,9.00,162.00,20/01/2019,90.00,,171.00,20/01/2019,,9.00,81.00,20/01/2019,90.00,,90.00"
```

Comment: You need to escape the `|`, because it's a [special regexp character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharacters.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this to replace all `'||'` strings with `','` char:

```
let output = transactions.split('||').join(',')
```

It also looks like your first `.replace` is not adding a '||' between elements in the array, so I'd recommend first using `transactions.join('||')`, then moving forward with your `.replace` then my code above.

Here's what the full code would look like:

```js
let transactions = [
    "   Date     ||  Credit   ||  Debit   ||  Balance  ",
    "20/01/2019  ||          ||  9.00  ||  162.00",
    "20/01/2019  ||  90.00  ||          ||  171.00",
    "20/01/2019  ||          ||  9.00  ||  81.00",
    "20/01/2019  ||  90.00  ||          ||  90.00"
];

let output = transactions.join('||') // 1. combine array with 2 '|' chars
    .replace(/\s/g, '')              // 2. remove all space characters
    .split('||').join(',');          // 3. replace '||' str with ','

console.log(output);
```

If you want to stick with the `.replace` function, you could use:

```
let output = transactions.replace(/\|{2}/g, ',');
```

This matches 2 instances of the `'|'` character right next to each other, anywhere in the original string, and replaces them with `','`. It's very similar to what you had, but as @Dan Dascalescu mentioned, you have to escape the `|` character in Regex **AND** you have to get rid of the comma in the `{2,}` piece, as this will match 2 or more `'|'` characters.

Here's how that would look in the full code:

```js
let transactions = [
    "   Date     ||  Credit   ||  Debit   ||  Balance  ",
    "20/01/2019  ||          ||  9.00  ||  162.00",
    "20/01/2019  ||  90.00  ||          ||  171.00",
    "20/01/2019  ||          ||  9.00  ||  81.00",
    "20/01/2019  ||  90.00  ||          ||  90.00"
];

let output = transactions.join('||') // 1. combine array with 2 '|' chars
    .replace(/\s/g, '')              // 2. remove all space characters
    .replace(/\|{2}/g, ',');         // 3. replace '||' with ','

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach, could be using the new experimental [flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/flatMap) for map every `string` to an array splited by `||`, and then apply `trim()` to each element of this new array to remove extra spaces, this new array will then be flatten, and finally we can join all elements with `,` to obtain the required  pseudo `CSV`. Note that this approach will keep the relevant spaces, for example, `Date And Time` won't be changed to `DateAndTime`.

```js
let transactions = [
    "   Date And Time     ||  Credit   ||  Debit   ||  Balance  ",
    "20/01/2019 09:57:00  ||          ||  9.00  ||  162.00",
    "20/01/2019 10:20:12 ||  90.00  ||          ||  171.00",
    "20/01/2019 14:17:30 ||          ||  9.00  ||  81.00",
    "20/01/2019 21:00:30 ||  90.00  ||          ||  90.00"
];

let out = transactions.flatMap(str => str.split("||").map(e => e.trim())).join(",");

console.log(out);
```

However, if you want a real `CSV` format:

> CSV is a delimited data format that has fields/columns separated by the comma character and records/rows terminated by newlines.

Then, you should consider adding the `new line (\n)` character to each new row of data, like on the next approach:

```js
let transactions = [
    "   Date And Time     ||  Credit   ||  Debit   ||  Balance  ",
    "20/01/2019 09:57:00  ||          ||  9.00  ||  162.00",
    "20/01/2019 10:20:12 ||  90.00  ||          ||  171.00",
    "20/01/2019 14:17:30 ||          ||  9.00  ||  81.00",
    "20/01/2019 21:00:30 ||  90.00  ||          ||  90.00"
];

let out = transactions.map(
    str => str.split("||").map(e => e.trim()).join(",")
).join("\n");

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use regex much but I would expect `.replace(/\|+/g,",")` to work. (It should find any number of consecutive pipe characters and replace the lot with a single comma.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
let output = transactions.join('||').replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/\|\|/g, ',');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join the array elements by `||` and use replace and in callback use function based on captured group return `''` or `,`.

This will save you using replace twice.

```js
let str = ["   Date     ||  Credit   ||  Debit   ||  Balance  ", "20/01/2019  ||          ||  9.00  ||  162.00", "20/01/2019  ||  90.00  ||          ||  171.00", "20/01/2019  ||          ||  9.00  ||  81.00", "20/01/2019  ||  90.00  ||          ||  90.00"];

let op = str.join('||').replace(/(\s+)|(\|\|)/g,
   function(match,firstMatch, secondMatch){
   return firstMatch ? '' : ','
})
console.log(op)
```